# Time zone conversion in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a date format, something similar to:

> Mon, 11 Aug 2009 13:15:10 GMT

How do I convert this to EST format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, or similar should do the trick:

```
var dateString = "Tue, 11 Aug 2009 13:15:10 GMT";
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
```

It's worth mentioning, that your originally specified *Mon, 11 Aug 2009*, is actually incorrect, hence I've changed it to *Tue, 11 Aug 2009* so the code will run, as the `Convert.ToDateTime` throws an exception if the day does not match the date.

I've also assumed that you mean `Eastern Standard Time`, which is the id associated with "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", but you can get a full list of the time zones available by running the following code:

```
foreach(TimeZoneInfo info in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", info.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("   DisplayName: {0}", info.DisplayName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var datetime = DateTime.Parse("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 13:15:10 GMT");
TimeZoneInfo estZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime estTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(datetime, estZone);
```

`EST` can mean different times, which do you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EST