# Timezone Conversion - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I am looking to convert this time: `Mon, 25 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT` into US EST. I know that this has been posted before here:[Time zone conversion in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537151/time-zone-conversion-in-c-sharp) but I am still getting errors having to do something with the string not being exactly right.

Here is my code:

```
var dateString = "Mon, 25 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT";
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Here is my error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles) [0x00000] in :0 
at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in :0 
at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in :0
```

at System.Convert.ToDateTime (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Program.Main () [0x00000] in :0

I have tried changing the date from `03` to `Mar` but I was unable to even get that to work. I have also tried the code in the other forum just to see if that even worked, but I was unsuccessful. I fully understand what the code is trying to do, but I just don't understand why there are errors being thrown.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Much of what you described here is just repeating what you already asked in your other question.  I don't see any question here about time zone conversion, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Your code is working on my machine. I just copied and try to run it successfully executed :)

Comment: Have you tried using this overload of DateTime.Parse:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx?

Comment: Also, the time zone id you are looking for is just `"Eastern Standard Time"`.  Drop the `"US "` from the front of it.

Comment: @MattJohnson: If at first SO doesn't solve your problem for you, just ask ask again.  :\

Comment: @MattJohnson I felt that it was a little different than what was being previously asked before. Sorry for the repeat though.

Comment: Did you try my answer from your other question?  If it doesn't work, please comment there.  When I suggested you ask separately for the timezone issues, I didn't mean for you to repeat the whole parsing problem again.

Comment: @MattJohnson I did not realize that is what you meant. I will hop back to the other forum. My apologies... I do really appreciate the help though.

Comment: No problem.  We're here to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing your date string to something like this:

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateString = "Mon, 25 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT";
```

should be this:

```
var dateString = "Mon, 25 Mar 2013 00:00:00 GMT";
```

EDIT: Fixed month.

Comment: I have tried this already. No dice.

Comment: Shucks, I thought it was just going to be something simple for you!

Answer (score 0):

If the string will ALWAYS end in GMT then you can use `ParseExact`:

```
var dateString = "Mon, 25 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                               "ddd, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT", 
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time"));
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you are doing with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` but it went away when i changed that to `null`. Even still both throw errors for me.

Comment: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is used to specify an unchanging (not customizable) culture that is not specific to any one region.  It uses English month and day names.  Did you change `Convert.ToDateTime` to `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: okay, I understand and yes I did change it

Comment: So what error are you getting now?