# Get Timezone offset from Country and State Name in C#

Tags: c#, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

Is there a way in C# to get the timezone offset for a given Country and State? For example, if input is Country - "Canada" and State - "Saskatchewan", then output is "-06:00"?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695439/get-the-default-timezone-for-a-country-via-cultureinfo

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I have already gone through this answer. It requires zone id information. I just have Country name and State Name.

Comment: @vidhi Canada/Saskatchewan is a valid TZ database timezone name.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the answer. It did help in finding the zone ids of different countries. 
Is there a way to find out the time offset from the zone id?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, modify the SO question's code like below to get `latitude` and `longitude`:

```
IEnumerable<string> zoneIds = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
    .Where(x => x.CountryCode == countryCode)
    .Select(x => new { x.Latitude, x.Longitude});
```

Then, one way is to use [Azure Maps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone/gettimezonebycoordinates) to fetch Offset and Transition offsets:

```
GET https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?subscription-key=[subscription-key]&api-version=1.0&options=all&query=47.0,-122
```

**Sample response:**

```
{
  "Version": "2019a",
  "ReferenceUtcTimestamp": "2019-06-17T22:16:59.0765556Z",
  "TimeZones": [
    {
      "Id": "America/Los_Angeles",
      "Aliases": [
        "US/Pacific",
        "US/Pacific-New"
      ],
      "Countries": [
        {
          "Name": "United States",
          "Code": "US"
        }
      ],
      "Names": {
        "ISO6391LanguageCode": "en",
        "Generic": "Pacific Time",
        "Standard": "Pacific Standard Time",
        "Daylight": "Pacific Daylight Time"
      },
      "ReferenceTime": {
        "Tag": "PDT",
        "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
        "DaylightSavings": "01:00:00",
        "WallTime": "2019-06-17T15:16:59.0765556-07:00",
        "PosixTzValidYear": 2019,
        "PosixTz": "PST+8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0",
        "Sunrise": "2019-06-17T05:12:21.267-07:00",
        "Sunset": "2019-06-17T21:05:18.017-07:00"
      },
      "RepresentativePoint": {
        "Latitude": 34.05222222222222,
        "Longitude": -118.24277777777778
      },
      "TimeTransitions": [
        {
          "Tag": "PDT",
          "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
          "DaylightSavings": "01:00:00",
          "UtcStart": "2019-03-10T10:00:00Z",
          "UtcEnd": "2019-11-03T09:00:00Z"
        },
        {
          "Tag": "PST",
          "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
          "DaylightSavings": "00:00:00",
          "UtcStart": "2019-11-03T09:00:00Z",
          "UtcEnd": "2020-03-08T10:00:00Z"
        },
        {
          "Tag": "PDT",
          "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
          "DaylightSavings": "01:00:00",
          "UtcStart": "2020-03-08T10:00:00Z",
          "UtcEnd": "2020-11-01T09:00:00Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Secondly, you can use [Google APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639571/get-local-time-based-on-coordinates) to get Local time using latitude and longitude:

```
    {
      "Version": "2019a",
      "ReferenceUtcTimestamp": "2019-06-17T22:16:59.0765556Z",
      "TimeZones": [
        {
          "Id": "America/Los_Angeles",
          "Aliases": [
            "US/Pacific",
            "US/Pacific-New"
          ],
          "Countries": [
            {
              "Name": "United States",
              "Code": "US"
            }
          ],
          "Names": {
            "ISO6391LanguageCode": "en",
            "Generic": "Pacific Time",
            "Standard": "Pacific Standard Time",
            "Daylight": "Pacific Daylight Time"
          },
          "ReferenceTime": {
            "Tag": "PDT",
            "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
            "DaylightSavings": "01:00:00",
            "WallTime": "2019-06-17T15:16:59.0765556-07:00",
            "PosixTzValidYear": 2019,
            "PosixTz": "PST+8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0",
            "Sunrise": "2019-06-17T05:12:21.267-07:00",
            "Sunset": "2019-06-17T21:05:18.017-07:00"
          },
          "RepresentativePoint": {
            "Latitude": 34.05222222222222,
            "Longitude": -118.24277777777778
          },
          "TimeTransitions": [
            {
              "Tag": "PDT",
              "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
              "DaylightSavings": "01:00:00",
              "UtcStart": "2019-03-10T10:00:00Z",
              "UtcEnd": "2019-11-03T09:00:00Z"
            },
            {
              "Tag": "PST",
              "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
              "DaylightSavings": "00:00:00",
              "UtcStart": "2019-11-03T09:00:00Z",
              "UtcEnd": "2020-03-08T10:00:00Z"
            },
            {
              "Tag": "PDT",
              "StandardOffset": "-08:00:00",
              "DaylightSavings": "01:00:00",
              "UtcStart": "2020-03-08T10:00:00Z",
              "UtcEnd": "2020-11-01T09:00:00Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```